# Regex to find strings containing at least two capitalized letters in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am looking for a regular expression that matches a specific string which has at least two capitalized letter in Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why stick to only ASCII letters?

This will match on two uppercase letters in any language using [Unicode character properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

```
/\p{Lu}.*\p{Lu}/
```

`\p{Lu}` is a [Unicode character property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that matches an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant

See also the [perlretut: More on characters, strings, and character classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#More-on-characters,-strings,-and-character-classes)

A little test:

```
my @input = ("foobar", "Foobar", "FooBar", "FÖobar", "fÖobÁr");

foreach my $item (@input) {
    if ($item =~ /\p{Lu}.*\p{Lu}/) {
        print $item . " has at least 2 uppercase!\n"
    } else {
        print $item . " has less than 2 uppercase!\n"
    }
}
```

Output:

> foobar has less than 2 uppercase!
> Foobar has less than 2 uppercase!
> FooBar has at least 2 uppercase!
> FÖobar has at least 2 uppercase!
> fÖobÁr has at least 2 uppercase!

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

`/^.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*$/`

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know exactly what you need:

```
perl -lane 'for(@F){if(/[A-Z]/){$count++ for m/[A-Z]/g}if($count >=2){print $_};$count=0}'
```

tested below

```
> echo "ABC DEf Ghi" | perl -lane 'for(@F){if(/[A-Z]/){$count++ for m/[A-Z]/g}if($count >=2){print $_};$count=0}'
ABC
DEf
```